# mx-auto for mobile screens otherwise normal flex

Tags: html, css, alignment, tailwind-css

folks,

Please, I'm experimenting with [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) *v2.1*. It look great, but I cannot find in documentation this problem.

Please, how can I do the [mx-auto](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#class-reference) in **flex** for the *center* object for mobile devices (when 2 pictures cannot be beside) but otherwise I want normal behavior. Yes, I can change the main `div` in every **card** from

```html
<div class="mt-5 px-2 md:px-5">
```

to

```html
<div class="mt-5 px-2 md:px-5 mx-auto">
```

And it's OK but the last card is centered as well when I have bigger screen (odd cards, last one is always centered). But I want center only when all cards are one under second.

One my card:

```html
<!-- First card -->
<div class="mt-5 px-2 md:px-5">
    <div class="max-w-xxs rounded-2xl shadow-md overflow-hidden bg-red-700 text-white">
    <figure>
        <img class="object-scale-down w-96" src="https://zrebec.sk/assets/tt1.jpg" alt="Man looking at item at a store" />
    </figure>
    <header class="flex m-2 justify-items-start font-semibold">
        <div class="inline-flex items-center border-2 border-black w-20 rounded-md mr-2 px-1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-4 w-4 mr-1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
        </svg>
        <span>186</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-flex items-center border-2 border-black w-20 rounded-md px-1">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-4 w-4 mr-1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
            <path d="M18 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 11-3 0v-6a1.5 1.5 0 013 0v6zM14 9.667v-5.43a2 2 0 00-1.105-1.79l-.05-.025A4 4 0 0011.055 2H5.64a2 2 0 00-1.962 1.608l-1.2 6A2 2 0 004.44 12H8v4a2 2 0 002 2 1 1 0 001-1v-.667a4 4 0 01.8-2.4l1.4-1.866a4 4 0 00.8-2.4z" />
        </svg>
        <span>12</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-auto font-bold w-100 text-right">84%</div>
    </header>
    <article class="m-2">
        <h2><a href="#" class="block mt-3 text-lg font-medium hover:underline uppercase text-center">Gold Retro</a></h2>
        <p class="text-gray-300 my-2">The Compact Cassette or Musicassette (MC), also commonly called the tape cassette, cassette tape, audio cassette, or simply tape or cassette, is an analog magnetic tape recording format for audio recording and playback. It was developed by the Dutch company Royal Philips in Hasselt, Belgium, by Lou Ottens and his team. It was introduced in September 1963. Compact Cassettes come in two forms, either already containing content as a prerecorded cassette (Musicassette), or as a fully recordable "blank" cassette. Both forms are reversible by the user.</p>
    </article>
    <footer class="flex items-center h-10 space-x-1 m-2">
        <div class="flex-1 text-center text-xs text-white font-semibold bg-green-500 px-3 py-1 rounded-md">Retro</div>
        <div class="flex-1 text-center text-xs text-black font-semibold bg-yellow-500 px-3 py-1 rounded-md">Continuous play</div>
        <div class="lex-1 text-center text-xs text-black font-semibold bg-red-500 px-3 py-1 rounded-md">Worse quality</div>
    </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whole code from playground is here:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/g2Zso9QsCv

Or here in codepen:

https://codepen.io/littleTheRabbit/pen/jOyzrLb

And please, I don't want use **Javascript** to block [mx-auto](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#class-reference) for last card. I think that `flexbox` can do that. Specially with Tailwind CSS. Please, try the [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) solution if is possible. I can write own CSS but then I don't need Tailwind. I want to discover power of [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/)

PS: I added **xss** size in the config file (otherwise is standard [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) Code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe grid does more of what you want.

```
<div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 justify-items-center max-w-5xl mx-auto">
```

Check our your example using grid:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/89CSaFNmLi

Comment: Yes. Grid are better. But I cannot limit grid-cols my screen size :) The cards can be 12 or more, not just 3. I read the documenation. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Add justify-center to

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap gap-5 justify-center">
```

Comment: I cannot ```<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center">``` center the last item to center of screen as well... Try you it to my codepen or Playground. If you add justify-center and you will have 2 cards beside and 1 under, the last card will be centered too. That's the problem what I talking about

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

Change the cointainer `<div>` to:

```html
<div class="grid justify-items-center sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:flex lg:flex-wrap">
```

This causes that I will `grid` with `justify-items-center` but in large screens I will have wrapped flexbox. Your opinion please?